# How to get event details using EventArgs?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, aws-lambda, eventargs

I am making an AWS lambda function and am given that when an event happens and my lambda function is invoked, the event object of my function handler will have properties of eventArgs.FirstName and eventArgs.LastName. I'm guessing I have to do something with the EventArgs class, but am confusing myself.

What exactly should my arguments be for the function? Currently I have (EventArgs e, ILambdaContext context). How do I get the FirstName & LastName that is sent to the function?

Comment: All event classes in .NET should inherit `EventArgs` as base.  You'd have to cast it to your class to look at properties (take a look at documentations for your API.)  For the source of EventArgs, look here: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/EventArgs@cs/1/EventArgs@cs

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model-handler-types.html)

The first argument by default is a stream , but you can specify any type you want as long as you provide a default serializer for it. You do this by adding an attribute on the method.

In your case:

```
[LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
pubic void Foo(UserEventArgs eventArgs, ILambdaContext context) {
 //do something
}

[Serializable()]
public class UserEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

BTW , you don't have to use/inherit from the EventArgs class at all. Just assuming this is something you already have.

Also add a dependency on Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json in your project.json file like this:

```
"dependencies":{


        "Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json": "1.0.0"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to create a new set of EventArgs, like this:

```
public class NameEventArgs: System.EventArgs
{
    String FirstName {get; set;}
    String LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Then, create an event delegate:

```
public delegate void NameEventHandler(object sender, NameEventArgs e);
```

Instantiate the event delegate:

```
public event NameEventHandler SomeEvent;
```

Define the method that will do something when the objective is completed:

```
public void EventHandler(object sender, NameEventArgs e) 
{
    // do something 
}
```

Assign that method to the event:

```
this.SomeEvent += this.EventHandler;
```

If you use this model, you should be able to add more values to the NameEventArgs object to help fulfill your lambda goals.